# Expressing polar complex numbers in cartesian form

Tags: complex-numbers

I need to express $z = 4e^{-i\pi/3}$ in the form of $x + yi$ and represent it on the Argand diagram.

I think that $4 = \sqrt{x^{2} + y^{2}}$ and that $\tan (\pi/3) = y/x$ but I haven't been able to do anything useful with this information...

Is this solvable via simultaneous equations?

Thanks!

Comment: In view of the answers posted, you should realize that it is MUCH easier computationally to convert from polar to rectangular form than to go the other way: $re^{i\theta} = (r\cos\theta) + i(r\sin\theta)$. You can do it in your head.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Euler Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/EulerFormula.html), $$e^{-\dfrac{i\pi}3}=\cos\left(-\frac\pi3\right)+i\sin\left(-\frac\pi3\right)=\cos\left(\frac\pi3\right)-i\sin\left(\frac\pi3\right)=\frac12-\frac{\sqrt3}2i$$

**Reference**: the [definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atan2#Definition_and_computation) of $\displaystyle\arctan\left(\frac yx\right)$

Comment: In my googling before posting this question, I did come across this method but avoided it since I haven't used it before.

Seeing you doing it shows it's rather simple but I have a question - What happened to the 4 in front of the e?

Comment: @Jacobadtr, just multiply the modulus$(4)$

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**

Use the [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula)
$$e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$$